# Check if onClick is fired or not

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

I am trying to determine programmatically if an element's `onClick` event is fired or not.
For example if the element is disabled then the event shouldn't fire.
This is what I've come up with:

```
function check(elm) {
   elm.exonclick = elm.onclick;
   var clicked = false;
   elm.onclick = function(oEvent) {
      clicked = true;
      if (elm.exonclick) elm.exonclick(oEvent);
   };
   elm.click();
   elm.onclick = elm.exonclick;
   elm.exonclick = undefined;
   return clicked;
}
```

so in this case the function should return true:

```
<a onClick="foo(); bar();" />
```

and in this case it should return false:

```
<a onClick="foo(); bar();" disabled="disabled" />
```

But I have 2 problems:

1. The expression `elm.exonclick = elm.onclick` is always null for some reason.
2. My custom `onclick` function is fired in both cases, even when it shouldn't. And therefore both cases return true which is wrong.

Comment: It seems to me, that your function doesn't stick to what you're trying to achive. You're expecting your function to return false if there's attribute "disabled" available - in your check function there are no attribute checking what-so-ever. And one more thing, if you're expecting `elm.click();` to really behave like user-issued clicked event you're in trouble since there's no way to do that in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As to first point of your question. Note that if the click handler won't be registered inline (in html code) or using `someelement.onclick = function() {...}`, you won't be able to access the handlers. In your case, you're using `onClick` attribute and then reffering to `onclick` (lowercase) maybe that's why it's null.